# Keeping the number of files in the folder constant by deleting old files

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, rm

I'm trying to create a script and run it in crontab every 5 min, so that the number of files in a folder always remain 50000. If there are more, I want the script to delete the old files.

```
#!/bin/bash
LIMIT=500000
NO=0
#Get the number of files, that has `*.pcap` in its name, with last modified time 5 days     ago

NUMBER=$(find /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.pcap" |wc -l)
if [[ $NUMBER -gt $LIMIT ]]  #if number greater than limit
 then
  del=$(($NUMBER-$LIMIT))
   if [ "$del" -lt "$NO" ]
    then
     del=$(($del*-1))
   fi
   echo $del
   FILES=$(
     find /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.pcap" -print0 |
       xargs -0 ls -lt |
       tail -$del |
       awk '{print $8}'
   )
  rm -f ${FILES[@]}
  #delete the originals

 fi
```

It doesn't really work, it doesn't run as the number of files are too large. Is there any other method to get this done?

Comment: You seem to have a typo in your script `tai` should be `tail`. Also if any of the filenames has newline in them `ls` into `tail` is not going to work

Comment: @Timo the files names dont have any new line characters and the script running on the linux system doesnt have any typos (thanks for pointing it though :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran the command:

```
find /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.pcap" -print0 |
  xargs -0 ls -lt | tail -n "$del" | awk '{print $8}'
```

The problem that I observed was that `awk '{print $8}'` prints the time, not the file name.  `awk '{print $9}'` would solve that.

Another problems is that `xargs` may run `ls -lt` several times which would give you a number of sorted lists of files one after the other, but the whole list would not be sorted.

But, there appear to be other simplifications one could make.  You can get the oldest files with:

```
ls -dt /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/*.pcap | tail -n "$del"
```

This assumes, as your post seemed to, that the file names have no spaces, tabs, or newline characters in them.

So, the full command for deleting the oldest `$del` files could be:

```
ls -dt /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/*.pcap | tail -n "$del" | xargs rm
```

**MORE:** If your file names may contain spaces, tabs, backslashes, or quotes in them (but *not* newlines), use (assuming GNU `ls` 4.0 (1998) or newer):

```
ls -dt --quoting-style=shell-always /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/*.pcap |
  tail -n "$del" | xargs rm
```

Comment: does the ls command have a limit on how much files can be shown? i mean does ulimit -s affect this?

Comment: @JishnuUNair I ran `ls -t` on a directory with 50,000 files with no problem using the default stack size of 8192.  After, reducing the stack size with `ulimit -s 100`, `ls-t`  on 50,000 files still worked fine.

Comment: It's not only newlines that are a problem with `xargs`, it's space, tab, single quote, double quote and backslash as well. Also note that `ls` might fail to execute if the list of files is big.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas OK, I added a solution for spaces, tabs, single quotes, double quotes and backslashes.  In my tests, `ls` worked fine on the 50,000+ files that OP wanted.  Under what circumstances will it fail?

Comment: Like all solutions that have a shell expand a wildcard in the arguments to a command, it may reach the limit on the size of arguments+environment passed to a command. That will depend on the number of argument and their size and the system and the version.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas As always, thanks for the info and also the edit.

Answer (score 5):

For those not wanting to make assumptions on the names of the files:

With `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
keep=5000
rm -f /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/*.pcap(D.om[$((keep+1)),-1])
```

That's using `zsh` globbing qualifiers:

- `D`: includes hidden files (**D**ot files).
- `.`: only regular files (like `find`'s `-type f`)
- `om`: reverse **o**rder on the age (based on **m**odification time)
- `[$((keep+1)),-1]`: only include the 5001<sup>st</sup> to the last.

(it may fail if the list of files to remove is very big, in which case you may want to use `zargs` to split it, or enable `zsh`'s builtin `rm` with `zmodload zsh/files`).

With relatively recent versions of GNU tools:

```
cd /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/ &&
  find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pcap' -type f -printf '%T@@%p\0' |
    sort -zrn | sed -z "s/[^@]*@//;1,$keep d" | xargs -r0 rm -f
```

(assuming GNU sed 4.2.2 or above (2012) for `-z`, GNU `sort` 1.14 or above (1996) for `-z`)

`find` builds a NUL delimited list of filenames with a Unix timestamp prepended (like `1390682991.0859627500@./file`) which is sorted by `sort`. `sed` removes the timestamp and prints only from the 5001<sup>st</sup> record. That's passed as arguments to `rm` using `xargs -r0`.

or (with any version of GNU tools):

```
cd /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/ &&
  find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pcap' -type f -printf '%T@@%p\0' |
    tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | sort -rn | tail -n "+$(($keep+1))" |
    cut -d @ -f2- | tr  '\0\n' '\n\0' | xargs -r0 rm -f
```

Same, except that we're using `cut` to remove the timestamp and `tail` to select the lines starting from 5001. Because GNU `cut` and `tail` don't support a `-z` to work on NUL delimited records, we use `tr` to swap the newline and NUL characters before and after feeding  the data to them.

With GNU `ls` (4.0 (1998) or above), and `bash`:

```
shopt -s dotglob
cd /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/ &&
  eval "files=($(ls -dt --quoting-style=shell-always -- *.pcap))" &&
  rm -f -- "${files[@]:$keep}"
```

(that also may fail if the list of file is big. Also note that it may include non-regular pcap files (no `-type f`)).

Standardly/POSIXly/portably, that's a lot trickier:

```
cd /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/ &&
  ls -dt ./.pcap ./.*.pcap ./*.pcap | awk -v keep="$keep" '
    function process() {
      if (++n > keep) {
        gsub(/[ \t\n"\\'\'']/,"\\\\&", file)
        print file
        file = ""
      }
    }
    /\// {
      if (NR > 1) process()
      file=$0
      next
    }
    {file = file "\n" $0}
    END {if (NR > 0) process()}' | xargs rm -f
```

(again, you may reach the limit of the number of arguments, and it does not check for regular files).

The tricky bit there is to handle the filenames with newline characters. Above, we're passing `./*` to `ls` which means `/`  will be included once for each file name, and we use that in `awk` to identify on which line each filename starts, then we know which newline character (in addition to all the other ones special to `xargs`) to escape for `xargs`.

Comment: Your first solution doesn't work as linux says 'zsh no interpreter found'. And I also tried the other two, they dint run either.

Comment: @Jishnu, you might want to install `zsh` before you try to use it...

Comment: For those trying this, note that debian stable (Wheezy) has `sed` version 4.2.1 which does not offer `-z`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming none of the file names contain space, tab, newline, single quote, double quote or backslash characters, this deletes the oldest files above limit

```
mkdir t && cd t

# 50500 files, 500 to delete
touch {000001..050500}

limit=50000

ls -t|tail -n "+$(($limit + 1))"|xargs rm 

ls|wc -l
50000
```

`tail -n +50001` shows files above limit.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ls` with descending sorting `-t`:

```
limit=5000
Cnt=0
for line in `ls -t`
do
  if [[ $Cnt -gt $limit ]]
  then
    rm $line
  fi
  Cnt=`expr $Cnt + 1`
done
```

Comment: command substitution doesn't split on newline, it splits on blanks (it also performs filename generation).